# .NET Core 2.0 assistance utilising 'Microsoft.Chart.Controls'

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I was planning to use `Microsoft.Chart.Controls` to create and then embed the image into the PDF report during render. When testing, I quickly realised that I was unable to run `SaveImage()` because of incompatibility with **.NET Core** (`DataBoundControl` Class is not part of **.NET Core**) and I've been searching high and low for a solution but failed miserably.

[image: Error when saving Chart image]

Any ideas on how the above can be achieved using **.NET Core**?

Comment: Have you tried this (https://www.grapecity.com/en/activereports) ? It is for .NET but not sure whether they have a newer version for .NET core.

Comment: With over 1500 rep, you should know by now that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @Adam No I haven't but will take a look. Thank you!

Comment: @Adam It's for .Net core

Comment: as alternative you can use any js charting library, and render it to image or PDF on the server with help of phantomjs or wkhtmltopdf/wkhmltoimage tools - and this approach gives you much more control over the output (you can apply custom CSS etc).

Comment: Have you found something for Charts on .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: @OracularMan See https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/78otug/net_core_20_alternative_to_microsoftchartcontrols/?utm_source=reddit-android Headless browsing is the best option due to the lack of System.Drawing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a .NET core binding for the cross-platform plotting library PLplot at https://github.com/DeepMLNet/PLplotNet.

It can output to all kinds of file formats, including PNG and PDF.

For a gallery of plots see the official documentation at http://plplot.sourceforge.net/examples.php. The color scheme can be changed easily if you don't like white on black.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the .NET bindings.

Comment: No disclaimer that you own this package.